# Gradient color in a treemap for D3

Tags: css, d3.js, gradient, treemap

*First of all this is different from the previous question asked in the posts, for what i am trying to achieve is a gradient for the entire treemap in d3, like what we have in google treemaps.*

I am trying to implement http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/ and working on the same, but in d3 i was trying to have a color gradient in it.

Currently I am doing this by

```
color = d3.scale.category20c()
```

and

`.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name)})`

on my svg element. But i want to have a gradiant color more like a heatmap, so as to make larger boxes in treemap more green and smaller boxes less green. is there a way in d3/css to specify that?

Comment: You can use [SVG gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp).

Comment: im interested in building something similar. Can I get access to the code in the link somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want a color scale applied to each box in the treemap. This is pretty simple:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(['lightgreen', 'darkgreen']) // or use hex values
    .domain([minValue, maxValue]);
```

Then apply with

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value)});
```

The hard part here is determining the domain - depending on how your data is structured, you might need to walk the tree to collect it. In the Bostock example, you can get the extent of the data after you've joined it to the elements like this:

```
d3.extent(d3.selectAll('rect.child').data(), function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Comment: Thanks. I also tried using d3.scale.ordinal().range([color codes required]).
This helped me to use my own color range as well.

Comment: i used this:
color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['009933','00CC33','00FF33','#3D9140','#4BB74C','#6AC06D','#81CD82','#62E46B','#CBF7CB','#FADEE0','#F6BABE','#FF9A9E','#EB7273','#FF4F56','#C80000 ','#D80000 ','#E00000 ','#E80000 ','#F00000 ','#F80000 ','#FF0000']).domain([d3.extent(d3.selectAll('rect.child').data())])

But this does not seem to color the nodes correctly? Could you please guide me?

Comment: You need a linear scale, not an ordinal. To use a linear scale, you need as many domain data points as range colors - so you'll need to interpolate between the lower and higher ends of your data extent to get as many points as you need in the domain.

Comment: I tried using a linear scale. The issue is range colors are limited and then they go around(domain is very large) and the colors are repeated. Also I am trying to color the child nodes in every container relative to them, instead of colouring on the basis of all rect.child nodes. Please correct me if I am wrong but selectAll('rect.child') takes in all nodes currently drawn in the graph, right? not pertaining to one parent container?

Comment: Yes, all nodes are selected - are you saying you want different color ramps for different parent containers? In that case, you'll need to make or reference different color scales for each ramp. It really sounds like you need a linear scale - what you describe is ordinal behavior. You want the scale to interpolate colors for calculated values, right? That's linear.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this.  (I'm a D3 noob.)  Is there a fiddle available so that I can see the code?