# D3 scale: mapping string to colors

Tags: d3.js

I need map strings to colors by using D3.scale. But I am not sure which scale best fits my needs.

the input will be many strings and the number of which is not determined beforehead. So I guess I cannot use .domain to specify the input strings. 
The output will be colors. I hope the range can be in ["hsl(150,80%,80%)", "hsl(250,30%,40%)"].

I tried

```
d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["hsl(150,80%,80%)", "hsl(250,30%,40%)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);
```

but it does not work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use one of the predefined colour scales, e.g. [`d3.scale.category20`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category20).

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, these colors are not enough, I need 50 colors probably.

Comment: Use a linear scale then, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839042/gradient-color-in-a-treemap-for-d3

Comment: I want something similar like category20. For example, is there anything like category100 or category200? I do not want to specify the domain.

Comment: No, there isn't. You could implement something that works in the same way as these scales (see the source code) with that many colours.

Answer (score 1):

```
  const domain = Array.from(new Set(someArray))
  const index = domain.indexOf(x)
  const col = d3.interpolateSinebow(index/domain.length); //give me 0 to 1 values
  console.log(col) // rgb(123, 123, 123)
```

Would that be good enough?

https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic