# Need help coloring in countries from an array, leave rest default color

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

I need some help taking the data from an array I created and then coloring only the countries that exist in the array in color, the rest of the countries that are not in the array I want left as default color. I am using D3 to do all of this, and I am pretty sure I can achieve what I need to via D3, but unsure how.

What I want to do, is take the country codes via data2 array, and based on their rank color them in dark red to green.

my array:

```
var data2 = [{name:"United Kingdom", country_code: 826, rank: 1},{name:"United States", country_code: 840, rank: 2},{name:"Sweden", country_code: 752, rank: 3},
{name:"Canada", country_code: 124, rank: 4},{name:"Germany", country_code: 276, rank: 5},{name:"South Korea", country_code: 410, rank: 6},
{name:"Australia", country_code: 036, rank: 7},{name:"Italy", country_code: 380, rank: 8},
{name:"Ireland", country_code: 372, rank: 9},{name:"Jamaica", country_code: 388, rank: 10},
{name:"India", country_code: 356, rank: 11},{name:"Mexico", country_code: 484, rank: 12},{name:"France", country_code: 250, rank: 13},
{name:" Japan", country_code: 392, rank: 14},{name:"Finland", country_code: 246, rank: 15},
{name:"Spain", country_code: 724, rank: 16},{name:"Russia", country_code: 643, rank: 17},
{name:"Philippines", country_code: 608, rank: 18},{name:"Romania", country_code: 642, rank: 19},
{name:"Ukraine", country_code: 804, rank: 20}]
```

Currently, to color my map I just do

```
 var country = g.selectAll(".country").data(topo);
  country.enter().insert("path")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("id", function(d,i) { return d.id; })
      .attr("title", function(d,i) { return d.properties.name; })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {return d.properties.color; });
```

See the problem is, I am using one set of data to create the map, and want to use another set of data, data2, to color in the specific countries.

I tried the below but did not work.

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
feature.data(data2.features)
             .enter().append("path")
             .attr("class", "feature")
             .attr("d", path)
             .style("fill", function (d,i) { return color(i) });
```

Thank you in advance for anyone that helps.

I can post all my code if necessary, but I did not want to fill the page up unless needed,

FULL CODE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3 World Map Template | TechSlides</title>
<style>
.country:hover{
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.text{
  font-size:10px;
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
#container {
  margin:10px 10%;
  border:2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #F0F8FF;
}
.hidden { 
  display: none; 
}
div.tooltip {
  color: #222; 
  background: #fff; 
  padding: .5em; 
  text-shadow: #f5f5f5 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 2px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #a6a6a6; 
  opacity: 0.9; 
  position: absolute;
}
.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #bbb;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
.equator {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>World Map Template with D3.js</h1>
  <p>Responsive D3 World Map with zoom and pan limits, graticule and equator lines, optimized TopoJSON with country names and colors, geo translation functions, geo coordinate plotting functions for points and text, and much more.  For a full list of features, please go <a href="http://techslides.com/d3-map-starter-kit/">back to article</a>.</p>


  <div id="container"></div>

<script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 9])
    .on("zoom", move);


var width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
var height = width / 2;

var topo,projection,path,svg,g;

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var tooltip = d3.select("#container").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip hidden");

setup(width,height);

function setup(width,height){
  projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([(width/2), (height/2)])
    .scale( width / 2 / Math.PI);

  path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(zoom)
      .on("click", click)
      .append("g");

  g = svg.append("g");

}

d3.json("data/world-topo-min.json", function(error, world) {

  var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

  topo = countries;
  draw(topo);

});

function draw(topo) {

  svg.append("path")
     .datum(graticule)
     .attr("class", "graticule")
     .attr("d", path);


  g.append("path")
   .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [[-180, 0], [-90, 0], [0, 0], [90, 0], [180, 0]]})
   .attr("class", "equator")
   .attr("d", path);


  var country = g.selectAll(".country").data(topo);

  country.enter().insert("path")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("id", function(d,i) { return d.id; })
      .attr("title", function(d,i) { return d.properties.name; });
  //offsets for tooltips
  var offsetL = document.getElementById('container').offsetLeft+20;
  var offsetT = document.getElementById('container').offsetTop+10;

  //tooltips
  country
    .on("mousemove", function(d,i) {

      var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map( function(d) { return parseInt(d); } );

      tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
             .attr("style", "left:"+(mouse[0]+offsetL)+"px;top:"+(mouse[1]+offsetT)+"px")
             .html(d.properties.name);

      })
      .on("mouseout",  function(d,i) {
        tooltip.classed("hidden", true);
      }); 


  //EXAMPLE: adding some capitals from external CSV file
  d3.csv("data/country-capitals.csv", function(err, capitals) {

    capitals.forEach(function(i){
      addpoint(i.CapitalLongitude, i.CapitalLatitude, i.CapitalName );
    });

  });

}


function redraw() {
  width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
  height = width / 2;
  d3.select('svg').remove();
  setup(width,height);
  draw(topo);
}


function move() {

  var t = d3.event.translate;
  var s = d3.event.scale; 
  zscale = s;
  var h = height/4;


  t[0] = Math.min(
    (width/height)  * (s - 1), 
    Math.max( width * (1 - s), t[0] )
  );

  t[1] = Math.min(
    h * (s - 1) + h * s, 
    Math.max(height  * (1 - s) - h * s, t[1])
  );

  zoom.translate(t);
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");

  //adjust the country hover stroke width based on zoom level
  d3.selectAll(".country").style("stroke-width", 1.5 / s);

}



var throttleTimer;
function throttle() {
  window.clearTimeout(throttleTimer);
    throttleTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      redraw();
    }, 200);
}


//geo translation on mouse click in map
function click() {
  var latlon = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
  console.log(latlon);
}


//function to add points and text to the map (used in plotting capitals)
function addpoint(lat,lon,text) {

  var gpoint = g.append("g").attr("class", "gpoint");
  var x = projection([lat,lon])[0];
  var y = projection([lat,lon])[1];

  gpoint.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y)
        .attr("class","point")
        .attr("r", 1.5);

  //conditional in case a point has no associated text
  if(text.length>0){

    gpoint.append("text")
          .attr("x", x+2)
          .attr("y", y+2)
          .attr("class","text")
          .text(text);
  }

}

var data2 = [{name:"United Kingdom", country_code: 826, rank: 1},{name:"United States", country_code: 840, rank: 2},{name:"Sweden", country_code: 752, rank: 3},
{name:"Canada", country_code: 124, rank: 4},{name:"Germany", country_code: 276, rank: 5},{name:"South Korea", country_code: 410, rank: 6},
{name:"Australia", country_code: 036, rank: 7},{name:"Italy", country_code: 380, rank: 8},
{name:"Ireland", country_code: 372, rank: 9},{name:"Jamaica", country_code: 388, rank: 10},
{name:"India", country_code: 356, rank: 11},{name:"Mexico", country_code: 484, rank: 12},{name:"France", country_code: 250, rank: 13},
{name:" Japan", country_code: 392, rank: 14},{name:"Finland", country_code: 246, rank: 15},
{name:"Spain", country_code: 724, rank: 16},{name:"Russia", country_code: 643, rank: 17},
{name:"Philippines", country_code: 608, rank: 18},{name:"Romania", country_code: 642, rank: 19},
{name:"Ukraine", country_code: 804, rank: 20}];

    d3.json("world-map.json", function(json) {
                //Merge the rank in data2 and GeoJSON in a single array
                //Loop through once for each "rank" data value
                for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
                    //Grab country name
                    var data2CountryCode = data2[i].country_code;
            console.log(data2CountryCode);
                    //Grab data value, and convert from string to float
                    var datarank = +data2[i].rank;
                        console.log(datarank);
                    //Find the corresponding country inside the GeoJSON
                    for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {

                        //We'll check the official ISO country code
                        var jsonCountryCode = json.features[j].properties.un_a3;
                        console.log(jsonCountryCode);

                        if (data2CountryCode == jsonCountryCode) {

                            //Copy the data2 rank value into the GeoJSON, with the name "color"
                            json.features[j].properties.labelrank = datarank;

                            //Stop looking through the JSON
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }

var color = d3.scale.quantize()
            .range(["Lime","GreenYellow","LawnGreen","LightGreen","LimeGreen","Green","DarkGreen","Yellow","Gold",
            "GoldenRod","DarkGoldenRod","Orange"    
,"DarkOrange","Coral","Red","OrangeRed","Tomato","Crimson","DarkRed","Brown"])
.domain([(d3.min(data2, function(d) { return d.rank; })),(d3.max(data2, function(d) { return d.rank; }))
]); 

               var country = g.selectAll(".country")
                   .data(json.features) //in my example, json.features
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .style("fill", function(d) {

                        //Get data value
                        var value = d.properties.labelrank;

                        if (value) {
                            //If value exists…
                            return color(value);
                        } else {
                            //If value is undefined…
                            return "#ccc";
                        }

 });
}); 


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's go step by step:

First, we'll grab the value for *rank* for each country in your data2 and we'll push that value in your GeoJSON, as a new property. Here is the code, that I got from Scott Murray (I see that in your code you use "topo" as a parameter name, but here I'm using "json"):

```
        d3.json("yourgeojsonfile.json", function(json) {

                //Merge the rank in data2 and GeoJSON in a single array

                //Loop through once for each "rank" data value
                for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {

                    //Grab country name
                    var data2CountryCode = data2[i].country_code;

                    //Grab data value, and convert from string to float
                    var dataValue = +data2[i].rank;

                    //Find the corresponding country inside the GeoJSON
                    for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {

                        //We'll check the official ISO country code
                        var jsonCountryCode = json.features[j].properties.iso_a3;

                        if (data2CountryCode == jsonCountryCode) {

                            //Copy the data2 rank value into the GeoJSON, with the name "color"
                            json.features[j].properties.color = dataValue;

                            //Stop looking through the JSON
                            break;

                        }
                    }       
                }
        //the rest of your code
});
```

Check if you have ISOa3 in your Geojson, or any other country code to match country_code in your data2.
Now we have a property named "color" in your GeoJSON, that matches "rank" in your data2. The next step is simple:

```
var country = g.selectAll(".country")
                   .data(topo.features) //in my example, json.features
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .style("fill", function(d) {

                        //Get data value
                        var value = d.properties.color;

                        if (value) {
                            //If value exists…
                            return color(value);
                        } else {
                            //If value is undefined…
                            return "#ccc";
                        }

                    });
```

So, if there is a value for d.properties.color, it will fill according to var color = d3.scale.category10(). If there is no value, it will fill with #ccc, or whatever you want.
Just to finish, if you want to fill them from red to green, dont use d3.scale.category10(). Instead, use:

```
var color = d3.scale.quantize()
            .range([ //put your colors here as an array ])
            .domain([d3.min(data2, function(d) { return d.rank; }),
                     d3.max(data2, function(d) { return d.rank; })
]);
```

For the colors, I recommend Cynthia Brewer's palette:

http://colorbrewer2.org/

**EDIT:** Only after reading the full code I realized that you are using TopoJSON. The code in my solution works for GeoJSON, not TopoJSON.

Comment: I added my entire code up above, I am still getting a few errors. Just to confirm, I did use JSON to get the world-topo.json file, so I should use JSON in the code from you above, not topo right? Ill keep messing with it, I really appreciate your help! Also I am using the UN country code, was not sure if that will work with the iso_a3, ill check and see if they match up.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't need to be iso-a3, all you need is a property in your geojson that matches your data2 country code. For example, regarding UK, look for any property in your geojson with the number 826. Then, in my code, just change **properties.iso_a3** for **properties.foo**.
If you did write _function(json)_ to load your geojson, you have to write json.features, not topo.features, in the rest of the code.

Comment: Oh, I see what is happening, now that you uploaded the full code: remove the **});** just above **var = country**. This was to close the d3.json function, see that it goes after the comment "the rest of your code" in my example.

Comment: Ah ok I deleted it, think its closer to working. It was complaining about zoom and throttle not being defined so I deleted em, but this is still an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on line 93. The county code is called "id" in the file, so i changed it to that properties.id and also it did not like json.features.length so i made it data2.length I'll update the full code in the OP

Comment: It has to be **json.features.length**, not **data2.length**, because you have way more countries in world-topo.json than in data2. I believe the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Ah I see. yea for some reason it says json is not defined, or Cannot read property 'length' of undefined for the line below                                                                       for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++)                                                                                     Do I need to initiate json in some other way or something? Its like it cannot understand json.features.length for some reason

Comment: The problem may be this: normally, a GeoJSON has this at the beginning:

{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[ etc... ]}.  So, "features" is an array of objects, and that's why j is between squared brackets. Open your "world-topo.json" and check if you have this structure. If you please copy it for me, I can check. And just a curiosity: why are you calling d3.json twice?

Comment: Hmm, I do not see that. Here is the link, http://techslides.com/responsive-d3-map-with-zoom-and-pan-limits  if you go to the bottom of the page there is a zip download link, its in the data folder once you download. yea I just caught that, accident. There is geometry collection, should it be json.geometry.length?

Comment: Try **json.objects.countries.geometries[j].id** for matching the country code, and push the color value inside geometries[j], like  **json.objects.countries.geometries[j].color = dataValue;**. For the length, try **json.objects.countries.geometries.length**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104761/discussion-between-gerardo-furtado-and-terry).

Comment: I got my plain map to work, but I really want to be able to zoom and hover to see names, so I am back at the Mike Bostock  map, and since I am using json instead of topo, I need this line to change but I am unsure how to change it,                                                                                   d3.json("world-map.json", function(error, world) {
  var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;
  topo = countries;
  draw(topo);
});                      Should I do json.features.countries and then do json=countries, draw(json); ?

Comment: So I am using the good new Mike Bostock map, and no errors, its printing out the country id's , etc, but for some reason its not coloring. There definitely are places where data2countrycode == jsoncoutnrycode so it should be recognizing it. But it just stays black no matter what,

Comment: I never worked with TopoJSON, so I'll need to have a look at the documentation. Regarding not colouring, try to console.log your GeoJSON after the "push" code, to see if the values are being pushed correctly.

Comment: Is there a way I can access coordinates? I tried json.features.coordinates but I cannot seem to do it. Using .data(json.features) is causing an error when coloring the countries, so I think I need to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a colour range using a scale, and not using ordinal values. You set the lower colour, the upper colour, and d3 works out where value d is between the min and max values and applies that percentage to work out the colour.

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(['lightgreen', 'darkgreen']) // or use hex values
    .domain([minValue, maxValue]);
```

Take a look here: [Gradient color in a treemap for D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839042/gradient-color-in-a-treemap-for-d3)